# easiest way to rotate a PNG file 90 degrees within R

Tags: r, image, png, raster

what's the most painless way to programmatically open a PNG file on my computer, rotate it 90 degrees, then save it as another PNG file - with no loss of quality and no other changes?  it's a five-second task in microsoft paint but all of the plotting, raster, image, device answers to related SO questions have me confused about the simplest way to do this?  thanks

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try package [`magick`](https://github.com/ropensci/magick#readme) :

```
library(magick)
newlogo <- image_read("https://www.r-project.org/logo/Rlogo.png")
newlogo <- image_scale(newlogo, "400x400") # logo is too big

# rotate
image_rotate(newlogo, 90)

# save    
image_rotate(newlogo, 45) %>% image_write("newlogoRotated.png")
```

I think that's the easiest way !

Comment: Uh... why the scale? That will produce a different image

Comment: The original logo is 800x700, a little large for RStudio viewer, it's just for the demo

Answer (score 1):

It's also possible to use the Bioconductor package [EBImage](http://bioconductor.org/packages/EBImage/), as in the following example.

```
library(EBImage)

# open
img <- readImage("https://www.r-project.org/logo/Rlogo.png")

# rotate
img <- rotate(img, 90)

# save    
writeImage(img, "Rlogo.png")
```